# Cassandra Triggers not being recognised by DataStax DevCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am working on a proof of concept Cassandra cluster - currently running the Datastax Community Edition (Cassandra Version 2.0.7) on x64 java 1.0.7_60 as a two node cluster (x2 Windows 7 machines). Everything has worked really well so far but my design depends quite heavily on triggers and I absolutely cannot get C* to recognise them correctly.

I can't get DevCenter (1.1.0) to recognise that anything is in the /triggers folder. This is true of the jar containing my own ITrigger implementation and the jar I compiled from the InvertedIndex example at https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers. Entering the CQL command (for the InvertedIndex example)-

CREATE TRIGGER test1 ON table1 USING 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.InvertedIndex';

- always returns

[image]

Things I've double checked -

- all the namespace / table name / trigger class names are correct.
- I am enclosing the class name in single quotes, the CQL statement itself looks fine.
- I've copied the jar files to the /triggers folder on both nodes.
- I've checked the Cassandra logs but can't see anything relevant.

I am only running on Windows while I am getting some Ubuntu boxes built, could it be anything to do with running on Windows?

Any suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated, I desperately want to keep this processing in the database and out of the client.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Cassandra or reloading the triggers (`nodetool reloadtriggers`) after copying the .jar file into the triggers dir? That would be needed for Cassandra to see the new triggers.

Comment: Does this work from cqlsh? Just want to make sure it's a DevCenter issue.

Comment: @BrianC - thanks for your comment - I did try reloading via the nodetool but there simply wasn't any triggers for it to reload.

Comment: @phact - I managed to add my trigger no problem using cqlsh and it's running perfectly. Put it down to DevCenter running on Windows I guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for cassandra trigger class not found issues with windows system.

[cassandra 3.5 fails to load trigger class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572209/cassandra-3-5-fails-to-load-trigger-class/55009477#55009477)